# video continue from paused state while clicking android home button

Tags: android

i am using video player in my application. its working fine. But i need while android "HOME" button clicking video player in pause state and again i click application it continue from last played state.

here my code:

```
videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
MediaController mediaController= new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);  
        String path1="http://commonsware.com/misc/test2.3gp";
        Uri uri=Uri.parse(path1);
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.setVideoURI(uri);

        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.start();    
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        videoView.pause();
        super.onPause();

    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        videoView.start();
        super.onResume();

    }
```

any one can help me?

Answer (score 5):

solved this issue. here my answer

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    try{
        if (videoView != null) {
            videoView.seekTo(position);    
            videoView.start();
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
                }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();    
    try{
        if (videoView != null) {
            position = videoView.getCurrentPosition();
            videoView.pause();         
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
                }
}
```

Comment: This solution worked for me as well  but another problem arise that is Hardware back key works only when pressed twice

Answer (score 0):

Please refer android API reference for VideoView

You can use the following methods to achieve this.

```
int getCurrentPosition ()
```

and

```
void seekTo (int msec)
```